# Extract URLs from a class using Scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I am trying to use scrapy to get a list of URLs from this website. I have the class of the div and I want all a tags in it.

here is the link for the website I am trying to get each URL for the profiles.

https://www.letsmakeaplan.org/find-a-cfp-professional?limit=10&pg=1&sort=random&distance=5

This is the code to try and pull the URLs from the page above

```
sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
books1 = sel.xpath("//div[@class='faceted-search-results-container-listing']/a/@herf").extract()
```

this comes back empty

This is is the code from the website

```
<<div class="faceted-search-results-container-listing" style="">
        <a href="/find-a-cfp-professional/certified-professional-profile/a9a0ca36-3c70-4ea4-a853-7f704fe4cc98" class="find-cfp-item js-card-link">
          <div class="find-cfp-item-top">
            <div class="h5 find-cfp-item-name">C. H. Simmons, CFP®</div>
            <div class="find-cfp-item-read-more"><span>view details</span></div>
          </div>

          <div class="find-cfp-item-bottom">
            <div class="find-cfp-item-column" data-column="1">
              <img src="https://login.cfp.net/eweb/photos/91475.jpg" data-default-img="/-/media/feature/cfp/lmapprofile/default-profile-avatar.jpeg" data-default-img-backup="/images/default-profile-avatar.jpeg" alt="C. Simmons Headshot" class="find-cfp-item-headshot" onerror="handleImg(this, event);">
              <div class="find-cfp-item-text">
                
      Simmons and Starzl Wealth Management<br>
      110 Bay St<br>
      Gadsden, AL 35901-5229<br>
    
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="find-cfp-item-column" data-column="2">
              <div class="h6 find-cfp-item-column-heading">Planning Services Offered</div>
              <div class="find-cfp-item-text" data-line-clamp="4">
                Investment Planning, Retirement Planning
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="find-cfp-item-column" data-column="3">
              <div class="find-cfp-item-column-inner">
                <div class="h6 find-cfp-item-column-heading">Client Focus</div>
                <div class="find-cfp-item-text" data-line-clamp="1">
                  None Provided
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="find-cfp-item-column-inner">
                <div class="h6 find-cfp-item-column-heading">Minimum Investable Assets</div>
                <div class="find-cfp-item-text" data-line-clamp="1">
                  $500,000
                </div>
              </div>

              

            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I added that piture to show the page that I am trying to scrape urls from

Comment: you can copy/paste the relevant part as formatted text

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `.../a/@herf"` -- this is wrong. It's `href`, not `herf`. Not that it would make a difference for that website though. Tell me what are you after from that website, to see if I can help.

Comment: I think she wants the href elements so the url links of that page. So this line  <a href="/find-a-cfp-professional/certified-professional-profile/a9a0ca36-3c70-4ea4-a853-7f704fe4cc98" class="find-cfp-item js-card-link">

Comment: No no, @ArundeepChohan. OP should tell us the ultimate goal: what sort of information from that website?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the search results come from an ajax call to an api in json format and rendered dynamically.

You can get all of the information from the raw json data if you scrape the api url instead...

```
scrapy.Request(url='https://www.letsmakeaplan.org/api/feature/lmapprofilesearch/search?limit=10&pg=1&sort=random&distance=5')
```

```
def parse(response):
    data = response.json()
    results = data["results"]
    links = [i["item_url"] for i in results]
    yield {'links': links}
```

output:

```
'/find-a-cfp-professional/certified-professional-profile/b1a27bac-77f0-4796-ab7f-7e15c19d8421'
'/find-a-cfp-professional/certified-professional-profile/e493f31f-88c7-4fdd-9863-9712ba85c95c'
'/find-a-cfp-professional/certified-professional-profile/2d634f05-331e-4699-b1a8-96e7a20aa0bf'
'/find-a-cfp-professional/certified-professional-profile/d9074216-7321-469f-b42f-2988d84d4a2b'
'/find-a-cfp-professional/certified-professional-profile/7f55e98c-df27-4922-b3a4-07c341a87f65'
'/find-a-cfp-professional/certified-professional-profile/1b0377a2-4545-45af-9ac4-18a8af2ffecd'
'/find-a-cfp-professional/certified-professional-profile/66b78e79-608b-4079-86c2-d9ae84c3a762'
'/find-a-cfp-professional/certified-professional-profile/e884f42b-8239-475a-b55f-5bb6f1130a36'
'/find-a-cfp-professional/certified-professional-profile/b00abd44-5969-4f02-a052-e6ef34b60e9b'
'/find-a-cfp-professional/certified-professional-profile/10ae9e9f-f11e-4f79-91c4-05f24e0c7a0e'
```